# Changing the source code of a function via RStudio without creating a new function

Tags: r

I need to change few lines in a function in package called `mirt`.

That function is  `fscores.internal` and is not a main function where you can just use `edit` or `fix` to change the code lines.

How can do this in RStudio?

I tried following:

```
library(mirt)
data(LSAT7)
LSAT7=expand.table(LSAT7)
mod=mirt(LSAT7, 1,itemtype = '3PL')
fscor=fscores(object = mod,method = "ML",response.pattern = c(1,NA,NA,NA,NA),theta_lim = c(-4, 4))


fscor
     Item.1 Item.2 Item.3 Item.4 Item.5  F1 SE_F1
[1,]      1     NA     NA     NA     NA Inf    NA
```

This is the final output. I need "theta_lim[2]" instead of "Inf" as F1's output which can be obtained when you replace the Inf by theta_lim[2] and -Inf by theta_lim[1] (at lines no. 278 and 280 respectively, in fscores.internal code. This is the only change I want to make.

After using `fixInNamespace("fscores.internal", "mirt")`

A window appeared containing :

```
function (object, ...) 
standardGeneric("fscores.internal")
```

(`fixInNamespace` was not helpful)

After using

```
myfscores.internal <- function() { ... }
assignInNamespace("fscores.internal", myfscores.internal, "mirt")
```

I got following error, when I ran

```
fscor=fscores(object = mod,method = "ML",response.pattern = c(1,1,1,1,1),theta_lim = c(-4, 4))



## Error in .local(object, ...) : could not find function "ExtractGroupPars"
```

Then I compiled `ExtractGroupPars` function separately.

then the out was

```
> fscor=fscores(object = mod,method = "ML",response.pattern = c(1,1,1,1,1),theta_lim = c(-4, 4))
Error in .local(object, ...) : could not find function "rotateLambdas"
```

After this I compiled `rotateLambdas` function

and I ran

```
fscor=fscores(object = mod,method = "ML",response.pattern = c(1,1,1,1,1),theta_lim = c(-4, 4))
```

Then I got following error:

```
Error in matrix(rep(sqrt(1 - h2), ncol(F)), ncol = ncol(F)) : 
  non-numeric matrix extent
Called from: .rs.breakOnError(TRUE)
```

Don't know what to do after this.

Comment: `fscores.internal` is pure `R`-code and easily accessed for editing from the source tarball.  That said, I strongly suggest **against** mucking with an internal method.  If there is an error in the package code, notify the maintainer.  If you just want to do something different, then write a wrapper or helper function to modify the output of `fscores` .  Internal functions are not meant to be mucked with.

Comment: And you used `assignInNamespace` or `fixInNamespace`? And what happened after you attempted to rerun the code after modifying the function?

Comment: @Thomas, I have edited question further, please add your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `assignInNamespace` to rewrite a function inside a package namespace. In this case you would define a new function and assign into the `mirt` namespace:

```
myfscores.internal <- function() { ... }
assignInNamespace("fscores.internal", myfscores.internal, "mirt")
```

Note: Behavior might be somewhat different if `fscores.internal` is exported from the package namespace.

Comment: thank your for your reply.

Here, I still need to create a new function; isn't there any better way?

Comment: Why is that a problem for you? You can always `rm("myfscores.internal")` to clean up your workspace.

Comment: now the problem is that there are few more functions which are  used in fscores.internal; now I think the new function  myfscores.internal is not recognizing those functions which were used already there in package source.

Comment: I don't think it's a problem, but you may need to reference those functions explicitly with something like `mirt:::otherfunction(...)`, etc. rather than just `otherfunction(...)`.

Comment: issue is not solved yet.When I did this:
myfscores.internal <- function(){...}
assignInNamespace("fscores.internal", myfscores.internal, "mirt") , there was an error showing mirt:::ExtractGroupPars not found, then I compiled this function again an error.
I even tried with a wrapper function then also it was throwing error, Where am going wrong? 
what I have tried:
library(mirt)
data(LSAT7)
LSAT7=expand.table(LSAT7)
mod=mirt(LSAT7, 1,itemtype = '3PL')
fscores(object = mod,method = "ML",response.pattern= c(1,NA,NA,NA,NA),theta_lim = c(-4, 4))

Comment: Item.1 Item.2 Item.3 Item.4 Item.5  F1 SE_F1
[1,]      1     NA     NA     NA     NA Inf    NA


This is the final output of the function. I need "theta_lim[2]" instead of "Inf" as F1's output which can be obtained when you replace the Inf by theta_lim[2] and -Inf by theta_lim[1] (at lines no. 278 and 280 respectively, in fscores.internal code. This is the only change I want to make.

Comment: @Irri Try editing those details into your question. It's not clear what you're doing based on the unformatted text in your comments.

Comment: I have edited my question, please have a look.